# how stack is used to timestamp graph DFS

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search

I have a quick question. When transversing backwards up a tree using DFS how does timestamp work?

eg.

if a graph has node 1 as the starting node. 1 goes to 2 and 2 goes to 3.

I have implemented some of the code below. It should return a 2d array for start and end times of each vertex.

```
boolean[] visited = new boolean[g.getNumberOfVertices()-1]
LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<integer>();
int[][] times = new int[g.getNumberOfVertices()][2]; //[i][0] == start,  [i][1] == end

int timer = 0;
stack.push(startingVertex);

while(!stack.isEmpty())
{
    int v = stack.pop();
    timer++;
    times[v][0] = timer; //start time
    int children = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < g.getEdgeMatrix()[v].length; i++)
    {    
        if(g.getEdgeMatrix()[v][i] == 1)
        { 
            children++;
            if(visited[i] == false)
            {
                stack.push(i)
                visited[i] = true;
            }
         }
     }
    if(children == 0)
    {
        times[v][1] == timer + 1; // end time
    }
}
```

This could be coded wrong but im a bit lost here.

This how this works is below:

node 1 popped and starts at time 1. node 2 added to the stack, then popped starts at time 1. node 3 added to the stack, then popped starts at time 3. No children so time ends at 4 for node 3. stack empty! exits while loop.

How can I transverse back to node 1 to end the time?

Comment: `children` is **always** 0, so the `if` statement is always true. The `children` variable is meaningless, and should be eliminated.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add children++

Comment: What is `start` in `times[v][1] == start + 1;`?

Comment: *"How can I transverse back to node 1 to end the time?"* Use recursion.

Comment: If you only want to go  3->2->1 push 3 as a starting vertex. There is no use of TimeStamp in your code. Only a counter (called timer) which increments when a vertex is pulled out of the stack.